# Moving android notification call of several projects with different class names to a common library

Tags: android, jar, notifications

I have several android projects that call the same notification function that I now want it to be moved to a common library for easy maintenance and may be converted to a jar file in future. However, each project will have a call to each project's own unique class name. So how can I do that? 
Hints: Check these lines, one project make call to project1.cls, another project2.cls, to bring the app back in front when the notification is tapped  by the user:
Intent notIntent = new Intent(context, project1.class); When the function is converted to jar, these classes will not be accessible by the jar !

```
private void showCommonNotification(Context context, String NotificationMessage,
        int Notification_ID) {

    Notification n;

    n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, NotificationMessage,
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    // Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, project2.class);

    Intent notIntent = new Intent(context, project1.class);
    //Intent notIntent = new Intent(context, getNotificationCls());

    PendingIntent wrappedIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: also, is it possible that the function inside the jar can call back a function in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in the class.

```
public static void showCommonNotification(Context context, Class<?> activityClass, String notificationMessage, int notificationId) {
...
 Intent notIntent = new Intent(context, activityClass);
...
}
```

To call:

```
Utils.showCommonNotification(context, YourClass.class, message, id);
```

Comment: I like your idea but I want to make the calling the same everywhere, so how to store the value Yourclass.class as a variable? showCommonNotification(context, YourClassVariable, message, id);

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect this method can exist in a utils class as a static method. In your calling classes you can do the following: declare a class variable `private Class<?> myClass;`  Then set the variable `myClass = Class1.class;`  or `myClass = Class2.class;`  Then call the static method `Utils.showCommonNotitication(context, myClass, message, id); ` Or as the example shows, just pass in the class when you call it.  i.e. `Utils.showCommonNotitication(context, Class1.class, message, id);  Utils.showCommonNotitication(context, Class2.class, message, id);`

Comment: You might also be able to use reflection to get the calling class by modifying the original answer like this: `public static void showCommonNotification(Context context, Object obj, String notificationMessage, int notificationId) { Class<?> activityClass = obj.getClass(); ... }`  Then you could call it like `Utils.showCommonNotitication(context, this, message, id);` from any class by passing in `this`